# перед И надо ставить запятую и почему?

Tags: пунктуация

Ведь враг обычно ищет слабое место, и если бы Шерлок Холмс выставлял его напоказ, то давно бы рисковал быть убитым.

Comment: Здесь не делают домашние задания. Предложите свой вариант пунктуации - и укажите места, которые у вас вызывают сомнения.

Comment: Пока могу помочь только тем, что запятая от предыдущего слова пробелом не отделяется.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что ДЗ.

Answer (score 3):

Запятая перед "и" *ставится* на основании присоединения к первому (простому) предложению целого сложноподчинённого. Возникает и вопрос о запятой на стыке этого союза с разделённым подчинительным союзом "если... то". Здесь запятая *не ставится*, поскольку изъятие условного оборота невозможно без нарушения общего смысла предложения (рядом оказываются и... то). Поэтому в исходном варианте верная пунктуация.

> Розенталь, Справочник по русскому языку: орфография и пунктуация,
> раздел 10, § 36 п.3
> http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=140#pp140
>
> *Холодной ночью…*
> *мальчик стучал в незнакомые дома, выспрашивая, где живёт Ознобишин, **и***
> ***если ему не отвечало мёртвое молчание, то** раздавался бранчливый окрик*
> *либо подозрительный опрос (К. Федин)*